# Extraneous spacing in marginnote with small font sizes

Tags: marginnote

With `\tiny` and `\scriptsize` font sizes, [`marginnote`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) adds extraneous vertical space after the first line. It seems to work fine with `\footnotesize` and upwards.

By comparison, `\marginpar` does not have this issue.

Assuming this is a bug, the question becomes: is there an easy remedy?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
\noindent text\marginnote{\tiny some long text here that includes two line breaks}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

marginnote inserts a \strut before your \tiny, and this gives a rather large spacing. Redefine \marginfont if you want to change the fontsize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\tiny}
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
\noindent text\marginnote{some long text here that includes two line breaks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has the problem that now the baseline of the margin note doesn't align with the baseline of the main text

Comment: Never mind, just solved my second issue as well (without redefining `\marginfont`, but instead just using `\marginnote{\strut\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\scriptsize#1}}`