# Slightly bigger line spacing after introducing vertical adjustment

Tags: vertical-spacing, marginnote, sidenotes

I use [`snotez`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/snotez) package to produce margin notes. I found that the vertical space between the first and the second lines became a little bit larger when I used vertical offset to shift the margin note.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-2.2\marginparwidth\relax}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.5\marginparwidth}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1.5\marginparsep}

\usepackage{snotez}
\setsidenotes{
  note-mark-format=#1.,
  text-mark-format=\textsuperscript{\hspace*{.04em}#1},
  text-format+=\scriptsize\raggedright,
}

\begin{document}
test\sidenote(\baselineskip){The is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

The output without offset:

[image]

You may notice that there is indeed an increase in the vertical space between the first two lines.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem is due to the `marginnote` package (which `snotez` will call). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594730/extraneous-spacing-in-marginnote-with-small-font-sizes).